# Is it possible to make Class.forName("") flexible?

Tags: java, class

before asking, please understand that my english is not good.

I'm using `Class.forName(...)` class in a servlet programming. when I access the servlet, I get a row of detailed controller information from Database indicating which controller to use.

This is `Class.forName(...)` I coded:

```
Class c = Class.forName(row.getControllerInfo);
c.newInstance();
```

This works fine, but there's a problem, i'm using Eclipse. The problem is that when I modified the Controller file, the changed contents were not applied to the server.,,.

Comment: Some code samples from your project may help us to see problem

Comment: Just to make sure: you do not cache the instances created with `newInstance()`, so on each request you call `newInstance()`?

Comment: I use IntelliJ and when I rename or move a class it gives me the option to rename it in strings and text/xml/properties files. Perhaps there is a similar option in eclipse.

Comment: I solved this problem with help of my senior. he told me how and the key was ClassLoader Class...thanks guyss!!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way is not to support dynamic loading. Much better to achieve something like dynamic update by supporting multiple servers. For development, you could get around redeploy delays by using JRebel (there might be others).

If you really do want dynamic loading of classes then the answer is "class loaders". I suggest having a look at those, and come back with any specific questions.

Comment: I found an another useful program which helps "runtime class loading",please visit here to see more infomation http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem true, 
When you change any file of your project, you must deploy your project to server. If you use server from eclipse, republish may solve your problem.

Comment: yes, i deploy all changed files but problem is it occurs only if i use Class.forName();

Answer (score 0):

have you tried clean - re-built and then deploying your application?